# Using Anchor Link In Nav Menu

Tags: menus

I've got two nav menu items that both get highlighted when I'm on a page (http://cafemangal.net/food-menu/)

Menu Item one links to: http://cafemangal.net/food-menu/

Menu Item two links to: http://cafemangal.net/food-menu/#DinnerCateringMenu

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: And which one should be highlighted?

Comment: They’re both the same page, so yeah, they’re going to be higlighted.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I'd like the "Catering" menu item highlighted when someone navigates to the anchor #DinnerCateringMenu